# How get count of column

Tags: oracle, count, sql-order-by

I'm rather new to oracle, and trying to figure out how to get the count of ports for each vendor that my query returns.

```
select distinct
  count(pi.port), pi.RACK, pi.SHELF, pi.SLOT, pi.PORT, pi.BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID, d.DSLAM, d.VENDOR, trim(d.model) as model, 
from
  table1 pi,
  table2 d,
  table3c
where
  pi.id = d.id and
  pi.circuit_id = c.circuit_id 
  and ((trim(d.model) not in ('TA5000','TA5004','TA5006','TA1248','TA1248V')) 
or (  (trim(d.model) not in ('C7','E7') or trim(d.model) not like '%E3-48CR2%' or trim(d.model) not like '%E3-48R2%') ) )
order by d.VENDOR
```

When I tried count(pi.port), I get ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.  How do I get it to give me the count of ports ordered by vendor?

Comment: Try adding `group by d.VENDOR` at the end.

Comment: I've tried group by.  It says "not a group by expression"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All columns from the `SELECT` that aren't aggregated have to be part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

Because of that, you don't need `DISTINCT` because `GROUP BY` will return distinct values anyway.

In your query, that would be

```
select 
  count(pi.port), 
  pi.RACK, pi.SHELF, pi.SLOT, pi.PORT, pi.BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID,   --> put all those
  d.DSLAM, d.VENDOR, trim(d.model)                                --> into GROUP BY
from ...
group by 
  pi.RACK, pi.SHELF, pi.SLOT, pi.PORT, pi.BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID, 
  d.DSLAM, d.VENDOR, trim(d.model)
```

**[EDIT, to show that such a GROUP BY actually works]**

Data doesn't really matter; I was lazy to create a *smarter* test case (as you didn't mind posting your own either). It is just to show that query doesn't raise the error you said it would.

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (id, port, rack, shelf, slot, broadband_circuit_id, circuit_id) as
  3    (select 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 from dual),
  4  table2 (id, model, vendor, dslam) as
  5    (select 1, 1, 1, 1 from dual),
  6  table3 (circuit_id) as
  7    (select 1 from dual)
  8  -- query goes here
  9  select
 10    count(pi.port) cnt,
 11    pi.RACK, pi.SHELF, pi.SLOT, pi.PORT, pi.BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID,   
 12    d.DSLAM, d.VENDOR, trim(d.model)
 13  -- your FROM clause
 14  from
 15    table1 pi,
 16    table2 d,
 17    table3 c
 18  where
 19    pi.id = d.id and
 20    pi.circuit_id = c.circuit_id
 21    and ((trim(d.model) not in ('TA5000','TA5004','TA5006','TA1248','TA1248V'))
 22  or (  (trim(d.model) not in ('C7','E7') or trim(d.model) not like '%E3-48CR2%' or trim(d.model)
 not like '%E3-48R2%') ) )
 23  -- my GROUP BY clause
 24  group by
 25    pi.RACK, pi.SHELF, pi.SLOT, pi.PORT, pi.BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID,
 26    d.DSLAM, d.VENDOR, trim(d.model)
 27  order by d.VENDOR;

       CNT       RACK      SHELF       SLOT       PORT BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID      DSLAM     VENDOR T
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- -
         1          1          1          1          1                    1          1          1 1

SQL>
```

Comment: Nope...it says not a group by expression when I try that

Comment: If that's query you really executed, then it shouldn't have raised that error. I edited my answer by providing a full example. As you can see, it *works*. If you claim that it does not, please, edit the question and post copy/paste of your own SQLPlus session so that we'd see what you did.

Comment: That is my query.  I just changed the table names and joins.  That shouldn't make a difference.  It's not SQLPlus.  It's Oracle.  Maybe that's the difference?

Comment: SQLPlus is a command-line tool which is used to work with an Oracle database. You probably use some GUI, instead. It certainly doesn't make the difference.

Comment: I commented out a couple lines that used decode and selected a couple other things like circuit_id since I didn't need them in count.  It fixed it.  Thanks! I kind-of wanted it to count every port under each vendor, but it's not doing that.  It won't let me get rid of d.model, pi.rack, pi.shelf, pi.slot, pi.port, d.dslam, etc in group by.  Is that the issue...the extra stuff in group by?

Comment: This did the trick: select 
  count(pi.port) as cnt, d.VENDOR 
from
  table1 pi,
  table2 d,
  table3c
where
  pi.id = d.id and
  pi.circuit_id = c.circuit_id 
  and ((trim(d.model) not in ('TA5000','TA5004','TA5006','TA1248','TA1248V')) 
or (  (trim(d.model) not in ('C7','E7') or trim(d.model) not like '%E3-48CR2%' or trim(d.model) not like '%E3-48R2%') ) )
group by d.VENDOR. Thanks!

Comment: As I said: if you use an aggregate function (such as COUNT) along with some other columns, all of them have to be part of the GROUP BY clause. If you omit any of them, you'll get an error. Once you remove those additional columns and leave VENDOR only, it *works* (does it return the correct result? No idea, but you'll know). And - you're welcome; I'm glad if you fixed it.